# sql server 2008 r2 wmi connection error [0x80041010]

Tags: sql, sql-server, wmi, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008r2-express

I am using sql server 2008 r2 and it was working fine but after restarting my computer it's not working , I tried to open configuration manager but it give me this error:

> Cannot connect to WMI provider. You do not have permmission or the server is unreachable note that you can only manage sql server 2005 and later servers with sql server configuration manager Invalid class [0x80041010]

I tried this command:

> mofcomp "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"

but sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof is not present in the shared folder and I don't know how to manage this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that definatly the correct path:

For x64 :

mofcomp "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"

For x86 :

mofcomp "%programfiles%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"